# Which indexes create to speed up a query with where

Tags: mysql, index, where

I have a query but I do not know which index create to speed-up it.

This is the query:

```
select
    `id_my_table`
from
    `my_table`
where
    now() between created_data
    and ifnull(finish_data, now())
    and `stato` = 1
    and `closed` != 1
    and `closed` = 0
    and `deleted` = 0
    and `id_my_table_type` in (3, 5)
```

I can not change the query, I just would like to speed-up.

If I `EXPLAIN` the query I see that mysql does not use any index.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: and `closed` != 1 -- redundant and could be removed.

Comment: @RickJames yes, I know, but I can not change the query (atleast for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run these queries to check the key distributionn

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mytable;
SELECT deleted,closed,stato,COUNT(1) rowcount
FROM mytable WHERE id_my_table_type in (3, 5)
GROUP BY deleted,closed,stato;
```

If the number of rows for `id_my_table_type in (3,5)` is small, then the index would be the following

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX closed_ndx (deleted,closed,stato,id_my_table_type);
```

Comment: The result of this query is 8618

Comment: @GiacomoM what is the sum of the rowcounts of the second query ???

Comment: the count of the original query results is 197 (the query you suggested me is 8618)

Comment: Then, the index I suggested should be good for you. After creating the index, run the EXPLAIN plan on your query. If the index is not used, then drop the index.

Comment: Note that that index has the columns tested with `=` first -- This helps make it optimal.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA  Would you consider using this request  

    ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX mytable_ndx_d_c_s_type  (deleted,closed,stato,id_my_table_type);  
for a more definitive index name?  Thanks for all you do.